# does onLocationChanged of the LocationListener get called on initialization?

Tags: android, locationlistener

I'm making a LocationListener. When created, does onLocationChanged get called? (Originally there is no location so it makes some sense that it is called)

Or is there some other way to get the current location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily test this question yourself...

But yes, if you create a `LocationListener` and call `LocationManager#requestLocationUpdates()`, then `onLocationChanged()` is called *after* the first location is acquired. Understand that if you are somewhere that cannot receive any GPS or Network signals (in a thick build or a cave) you may never receive a location fix...